# I Paid my friend's phone bill now there is a debt collector coming after me

Tags: debt, collections

A few months back I had purchased a phone for my friend. The agreement between us was that I would pay for one month and that would be it. The store employee assured me it would not have any recurring payments.

My name was not provided, they had signed all the documentation and the only way it was tied to my name was with my credit card.

I am working on a debt validation letter tonight. I'm guessing since I did not sign the agreement it will be dropped. I did not receive a formal letter in the mail, they have only tried to text me (I believe they also tried to call using a job offer as a way to get me on the phone. A person from India with broken English offered me a job over a voicemail in the same city where I had purchased the phone.)

Does anyone have suggestions on what I should include in the letter? Any other insights?

Comment: Are you sure its a valid debt collection attempt and not a scam?

Answer (score 1):

> My name was not provided, they had signed all the documentation and the only way it was tied to my name was with my credit card.

Based on this, it seems that you did not sign the contract so you are not legally liable.

They probably just tried to charge the credit card on file, which was yours.